# How to check unique int number in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can we check if the number generated through
I am trying to generate a unique number in between 0 to 10.

> **randomNumber = arc4random() % 10;**

is unique or not??

i am able to generate a random number, but not able to check,whether its unique or not?

Thanks

Comment: Without definition (i.e., unique to what?) there are no unique numbers. Every number that can be generated has been seen before.

Comment: unique- a number which doesnot repeat.

Comment: even if the number is truly random (it isn't unless there is a true random number generator hardware), repetition is possible and not invalid. If you're wanting to make certain that there are zero repetitions, you should create a list of all possible values you will accept and order the list randomly, then draw values from the list no more than once per value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid duplication, refer a following random number generation code. When you run the following code also does not overlap any number. If you mean you want it unique.

```
#define COUNT 1000
#define RANGE 1000
int num[COUNT];

bool isNew(int idx, int val)
{
    for (int i=0; i<idx; i++) 
    {
        if (num[i] == val) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
for (int i=0; i<COUNT; i++)
{
    do
    {
        num[i]=arc4random()%RANGE;        
    }
    while (!isNew(i, num[i]));
    NSLog(@"%d ", num[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save all generated numbers in an array and check whether there are two duplicates.

The more number you have, the more is sure that the generated numbers are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...this will give you all the possible unique number set in Mutable array...

```
-(NSInteger) randomNumber {
NSInteger newRandomNumber = (NSInteger) arc4random() % 10;
NSInteger uniqueNumber;
if ([self.arrayContainingNumbers containsObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:newRandomNumber]]) {
    [self randomNumber];
    } else {
    [self.arrayContainingNumbers addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:newRandomNumber]];
}
uniqueNumber = [[self.mutableArrayContainingNumbers lastObject]integerValue];
     NSLog(@"new Unique Number is %ld",(long)uniqueNumber);

return uniqueNumber;  }
```

Don't forget to add this method :)

```
-(NSMutableArray *) arrayContainingNumbers {
if (!_mutableArrayContainingNumbers) {
    _mutableArrayContainingNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return _mutableArrayContainingNumbers; }
```